# How to make class which will delete particular fields from custom object, if records are older than 60 days?

Tags: apex, custom-object, custom-field, scheduled-apex

This is my code, but it's deleting whole record, not only this fields.

```
global class BankApplicationFieldsDelete implements Schedulable{

global void execute(SchedulableContext SC){
    list<Bank_Application__c> BankApplicationsToDelete=[SELECT field1__c, field2__c FROM Bank_Application__c WHERE CreatedDate<LAST_N_DAYS:60];
        if(BankApplicationsToDelete!=null)
            delete BankApplicationsToDelete;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want to "delete" the fields, but rather clear them out. That involves an **`update`**:

```
public void execute(SchedulableContext context)
{
    List<Bank_Application__c> applications = [
        SELECT Id FROM Bank_Application__c
        WHERE CreatedDate < N_DAYS_AGO:60
    ];
    for (Bank_Application__c application : applications)
    {
        application.Field1__c = null;
        application.Field2__c = null;
    }
    update applications;
}
```

Note that you don't need to use the `global` accessibility modifier for `Schedulable` classes. In fact, unless you are building a REST/SOAP endpoint, managed package, or some utility for general distribution, you should pretty much never use it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56183/discussion-on-answer-by-adrian-larson-how-to-make-class-which-will-delete-partic).

Answer (score 2):

You will have to set the fields to the `null` value. Then call an `update` instead of a `delete`:

```
List<Bank_Application__c> applications = [SELECT Id FROM Bank_Application__c WHERE CreatedDate<LAST_N_DAYS:60 AND (field1__c != null OR field2__c != null)];

for(Bank_Application__c application : applications){
     application.field1__c = null;
     application.field2__c = null;
}

update applications;
```

Comment: Note that you don't actually care about the current values of `Field1__c` and `Field2__c`, so you can omit them from your query.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Is it not reducing the potential size of the records returned? This is not necessary to set the null values on fields that are already set to null no?

Comment: I just mean you can remove them from the SOQL and save a few characters of code. In theory it would slightly reduce your heap usage, but the effect there is probably negligible. More than either of those factors, though, for me it's a paradigm thing. For instance sometimes you already have the Id and can just update the record based on that, but you see developers still re-query because they *think* they need the current field values.

Comment: @AdrianLarson omg Thanks ! That's the second thing I realized I was doing wrong the whole time since I joined this community. The first was to always check if an element was already contained in a Set before adding it.....